# How to define a Bower dependency to a Git repository with no releases tagged?

Tags: bower

Trying to add a dependency to [arbor](https://github.com/samizdatco/arbor) using Bower. This JS library does not have any releases tagged in GitHub, but has been published to Bower. How should the dependency look in `bower.json`?

```
"dependencies": {
   "arbor": ...
}
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

As it is written in the [documentation](http://bower.io/), you can specify the package in form of a remote Git endpoint:

```
"dependencies": {
    "some-package": "git://github.com/someone/some-package.git"
 }
```

Since GitHub is usually used, there is a shortcut for this (unless specified otherwise):

```
"dependencies": {
    "some-package": "someone/some-package"
 }
```

This will download the newest version of the package. To make sure that your app will work with the downloaded version, you can specify the commit with its hash. So this

```
"dependencies": {
    "some-package": "someone/some-package#ddb859e7e7d2beb9c7ecd54cfe4ea2e67ac1d797"
 }
```

will always download the package in the state of that specific commit.

**Update:** Changed protocol from SSH (`git@github.com:`) to plain git (`git://github.com/`) as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Also, you have to use the full hash. A partial just looks for a tag/branch of that name.

Comment: And how does one find out what the hash is? This information would be useful.

Comment: I tried the first example and got an error, `Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.` So I looked at the github documentation that was linked to and used `bower install git://github.com/user/package.git`.

Comment: @AdamS, thanks. To use `git@github.com:` you need to have SSH set up. I edited the answer.

Comment: Not sure if this answer still apply, but I'm trying to do this and i can't

Comment: @DannyG, it should work all right, I have just retested it. What exactly does not work properly?

Comment: I changed it to `(git://github.com/)` and it worked after, also i had to do `bower cache clean`

Comment: My network does not allow `git://` protocol. Is there a way to indicate by `https://`?

Comment: @RomulusUrakagiTs'ai I have the same problem - did you manage to find any solutions?

Comment: @GauravOjha Sometimes simply change `git://github.com/foo/bar.git` to `https://github.com/foo/bar` works, but sometimes not. I don't know the rule but maybe you can take a try.

Comment: @RomulusUrakagiTs'ai thanks for the prompt response sir. I'll give it a try!