# How to specify a particular provider of a bower dependency

Tags: bower, angular-cookies

I want to use `angular-cookies` from bower but when I do:

`bower install angular-cookies` it sometimes fetches [the one published by the angular team](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies) and sometimes some other [old incompatible one from an independent author (angularify)](https://github.com/angularifyjs/angular-cookies)

If I do manage to get the official one, then whenever I run `bower install ...` again, for some other reason, bower will switch the version of *angular-cookies* that I already have, breaking my application.

How can I do something like:

`bower install --force https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [doc](https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/json.md#dependencies) specifies - you can add something like:

```
"dependencies": {
   "angular-cookies": "git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies"
}
```

Which will cause bower to get the dependency from the git repo you want.  You can also use `git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies#branch_name` or `git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies#tag_name` to specify a specific branch or tag.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311804/how-to-define-a-bower-dependency-to-a-git-repository-with-no-releases-tagged)  as well.